# How do I configure my tsconfig with pixijs v5?

Tags: typescript, pixi.js

I'm having an odd issue properly importing PIXI js in my typescript project.

The problem is I never have to use the PIXI prefix when referencing a PIXI object.

For example instead of:

```
let s = new PIXI.Sprite(textureName);
```

I have to do:

```
let s = new Sprite(textureName);
```

Everything works, it's just kind of an annoyance. I have a feeling it's how my tsconfig.json file is configured.

How can I configure it so it behaves like the first option?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target":"es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "tester",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "gsap": "^2.1.3",
    "howler": "^2.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/facebook-js-sdk": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/gsap": "^1.20.2",
    "@types/howler": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/pixi.js": "^4.8.7",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "npm-install-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.5",
    "pixi.js": "^5.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4",
    "webpack": "^4.29.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Here is a sample ts file.

```
import { Sprite, Texture } from "pixi.js";
import { IGameComponent } from "../interfaces/game-component.interface";

export class BaseSprite extends Sprite implements IGameComponent {
  constructor(texture?: Texture) {
    super(texture);
    this.interactive = false;
    this.interactiveChildren = false;
  }

  init(): void {
  }

  update(delta: number): void {
  }
}
```

Comment: does `import Pixi from "pixi.js";` not work? What about `import * as Pixi from "pixi.js";`?

Comment: The first option says 'pixi.js has no default export' but the second option did the trick! Thank you for the help!

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak Actually, cancel that. It compiles correctly but at runtime I get a 'Uncaught ReferenceError: PIXI is not defined' in the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should import PixiJS like this:

```
import * as PIXI from "pixi.js";
```

This imports all the elements from pixi.js and puts them into the `PIXI` namespace.

What you are currently doing is only importing a few elements and putting them directly into the `Sprite` and `Texture` variables:

```
import { Sprite, Texture } from "pixi.js";
```

The ES module syntax can be confusing, but it allows for a lot of flexibility. You can limit exactly what is imported. You can also rename any module or part of a module as you desire. (Useful when two libraries use the same name). This reference lists [all the ways `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Syntax) can be used.

---

**update:**

In addition, some plugins assume the existence of `PIXI` in the global namespace. Starting from version 5, there is no longer a global `PIXI`. The [v5 migration guide](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/wiki/v5-Migration-Guide#bundling-changes) explains how to fix this:

The quick and dirty fix is to put `PIXI` in the global namespace like this:

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
window.PIXI = PIXI; // some bundlers might prefer "global" instead of "window"
```

The better solution is to shim the `PIXI` global in the webpack config. (See details from link above.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried out the 'import * as PIXI from "pixi.js";' and it all compiled just fine but threw an error in the console at run time saying 'Uncaught ReferenceError: PIXI is not defined'. I'm using webpack. Maybe that isn't configured correctly?

Comment: I never even noticed the migration guide. Thanks a million for the help!

Answer (score 4):

For pixi.js v5 you should add the "pixi.js" module to your tsconfig.json like types in the compilerOptions section. And remove the @types/pixi.js module.

```
tsconfig.json
{...
"compilerOptions": {
   ...,
   "types": ["pixi.js"],
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use types definitions from the npm package:

```
tsconfig.json
{...
"compilerOptions": {
   ...,
    "typeRoots" : ["node_modules/pixi.js"],
    "types" : ["pixi.js"],
   }
}
```

Example of project:
https://github.com/andreytmk/pixijs5-ts-dev